# Want to remove Allow Access page while logging in into the app

Tags: react-native

I want to remove Allow Permissions page while logging-in in to my application.
I am using SalesforceMobileSDK-ReactNative.
PFA for reference.[image: The Allow Access page]

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-authorize users in your Org if you wish to skip this Allow Access screen for those users.  The following instructions were found here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8Wn5SAF.

1. Navigate to Create->Apps, and click on your connected app.
2. Click on Manage, then click on Edit Policies
3. Change OAuth Policies->Permitted Users to "Admin approved users are pre-authorized"
4. Click on the Manage Profiles button (in a related list further down the Manage App page)
5. Add the profiles which are pre-authorized, and will not be required to grant access.

Now the users under that profile will not be asked to grant access to your connected app.  Hope this helps!